# Displaying recursively multidimensional, different depth array in blade

Tags: php, laravel, recursion

I'want to display multidimensional array in blade using subviews.

```php
$arr = [ 923, 100 => [ 123, 158, 12 => [ 999, 998 ] ], 111, 12 ];
```

Blade view:

```
@foreach ($arr as $a)
    @if (is_array($a))
        @include('inc', ['a' => $a])
    @else
        <p>{{ $a }}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Subview `inc`:

```
@foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
    @if (is_array($value))
        @include('inc', array('value', $value)) 
    @else
        <p>{{$value}}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

As a result I get infinite loop. What is wrong?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing invalid name to the subview.
Instead of doing:

```
@foreach($arr as $key => $value)
    @if (is_array($value))
        @include('inc', array('value', $value)) 
    @else
        <p>{{$value}}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Where you're passing variable with name `value` to the subview `inc`, and you're iterating over `$arr` variable. You're not changing the value of `$arr` so its value it is not changed and you're iterating it over and over again.

You should do:

```
@foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    @if (is_array($value)) 
        @include('inc', [ 'arr' => $value ])
    @else
        <p>{{ $value }}</p>
    @endif
@endforeach
```