# nested triple array with foreach php-laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have nested arrays, I want to return them with foreach but when I get to 3rd array I get an error.

Error output: **htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of the given array type**

Following my code:

```
 $array = array(
            "fruits" => array("Apple" => array("Sweet Apple", "Sour Apple") , "Orange", "Pear"),
            "vegetables" => array("Pepper" => array("Hot Pepper", "Sweet Pepper"), "Onion", "Aubergine"),
            "names"  => array("John", "Smith")
        );

@foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }}
    @foreach($value as $secondValue)
        <li>{{ $secondValue }}</li>

        @foreach($secondValue as $thirdKey => $thirdValue)
            <li>{{ $thirdValue }}</li>
        @endforeach

    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

dd output :

[image]

Comment: Standard debugging tip: print everything to see where something goes wrong. This includes printing the indexes. In particular, make sure your indexes are integers, not strings

Comment: pay attention in the second loop... you are trying to print the entire sub array instead of it's key

Comment: ```Orange``` doesn't have sub array , so you can't use loop

Comment: How do you want the output to be can you provide the output as a sample? Of this case?

Comment: I want the output to be like parent-child relationship @RajeshPaudel

Comment: Ok let me try to answer it. I might not have understood correctly. But feel free to comment

Comment: Related [Displaying recursively multidimensional, different depth array in blade](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64210503/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you wanted to print in parent child like relationship below code should work fine

```
 $array = [
    "fruits" => ["Apple" => ["Sweet Apple", "Sour Apple"] , "Orange", "Pear"],
    "vegetables" => ["Pepper" => ["Hot Pepper", "Sweet Pepper"], "Onion", "Aubergine"],
    "names"  => ["John", "Smith"]
 ]
  

@foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {{ $key }}
    <ul>
    @if(is_array($value))
    @foreach($value as $name => $secondValue)
        <li>
            {{ is_array($secondValue) ? $name : $secondValue }}
            @if(is_array($secondValue))
            <ul>
                @foreach($secondValue as $thirdKey => $thirdValue)
                    <li>{{ $thirdValue }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
            @endif    
        </li>
    @endforeach
    @endif
    </ul>
@endforeach
```

As for why your implementation gave error is that the **$secondValue** will sometimes have array sometimes string. If it's string you will encounter an error since the foreach expects array to be it's parameter. You are encountering error on **Orange** of **fruits** key.